# Set the candlestick width in Plotly

Tags: plotly, candlestick-chart

[image]

In the attached picture, the candlestick's width are different for weekly and daily chart. Does somebody know how to force them the same? Both of them are plotting the same number of candles.

Comment: In the attached picture, the candlestick's width are different for weekly and daily chart. Does somebody know how to force them the same? Both of them are plotting the same number of candles.

Comment: As @bob-raymond says below (as of June 2022), Plotly doesn't expose a candlestick width parameter :-(   As a workaround, has anyone found a way to reach down into the underlying D3 library to enable controlling candlestick width?

Comment: Another workaround possibility is to adjust the enclosing `div` width.  While experimenting, I started with `<div id="myPlot" style="width:100%;max-width:700px"/>`.  The few candlesticks I plotted were very wide. But when I changed  `max-width` to `300px`, Plotly shrunk the plot and candlestick width.

Answer (score 0):

- candlestick width is defined by number of candlesticks that are in a figure
- an approach to making them the same width is to plot the same number of candlesticks in various views
- below shows this technique - `tail()` dataframe so daily plot has same number of candlesticks as weekly plot

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# generate some data
df = pd.DataFrame({"time": pd.date_range("1-jan-2021", "now", freq="4H")}).pipe(
    lambda d: d.assign(val=np.random.uniform(5, 10, len(d)))
)


def candleFig(df, freq, rows=None, title=None):
    df2 = df.set_index("time").resample(freq).ohlc().droplevel(0, 1)
    if rows:
        df2 = df2.tail(rows)

    return (
        go.Figure(
            data=[go.Candlestick(x=df2.index,
                               open=df2["open"], high=df2["high"],low=df2["low"], close=df2["close"],)]
        ).update_layout(xaxis={"rangeslider": {"visible": False}}, margin={"t": 25, "b": 0},
                        height=150,width=1000, title={"text": title},),
        df2,
    )


fig_w, df_w = candleFig(df, "1W", title="Weekly")
fig_d, df_d = candleFig(df, "1D", rows=len(df_w), title="Daily")

fig_w.show()
fig_d.show()
```

Comment: I appreciate your resourcefulness in finding this workaround.  Unfortunately, I'm too lazy to use it.